# Moving windows left/right/up/down between multiple monitors on KDE

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

Is there any way to configure a keyboard shortcut to move a window to the left/right/up/down monitor? The only action I see in System Preferences -> Shortcuts and Gestures are "Window to previous screen" and "Window to next screen", which I am not sure how it relates to left/right/up/down monitor (I don't know what ordering Kubuntu uses to define "previous" and "next").

[image]

I use Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hunting the same functionality and found in the shortcuts/KWin settings:

***quick tile window to the left/right*** will maximize it to the left/right.

It doesn't look like top/bottom functionality exists.

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=310005

***Window to Next/Previous Screen*** works for moving windows to other monitors.

I'm hoping to find more, but so far KDE is not quite as friendly with multiple windows on multiple monitors as Win7 or even Ubuntu with compiz.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Num (keypad)</kbd> control where you want your windows.